# Select global min() in a new column for all rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table db_race

```
--------------------------
| Name    | Time | Map   |
--------------------------
| Max     | 240  | test1 |
| Alvin   | 600  | test2 |
| Amanda  | 234  | test1 |
| Angela  | 50   | test1 |
| Angela  | 2000 | test1 |
--------------------------
```

I now want to select some rows ordered by best Time on a map like the following

```
SELECT Name, min(Time) AS Time 
FROM db_race 
WHERE Map='test1' 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY Time ASC
```

That works perfectly fine, but I want to have the best time of all records added to another column looking like the following. (will later work with that but thats not a part of the question)

```
----------------------------
| Name    | Time | TopTime |
----------------------------
| Angela  | 50   | 50      |
| Amanda  | 234  | 50      |
| Max     | 240  | 50      |
----------------------------
```

So far I tried the following but it only shows the best time, I want it for the whole selected table

```
SELECT *, min(Time) AS TopTime 
FROM (SELECT Name, min(Time) AS Time 
      FROM db_race 
      WHERE Map='test1' 
      GROUP BY Name 
      ORDER BY Time ASC) a
```

I want to make sure I dont need to find the TopTime by using a subquery. The actual query will be very long and my goal is to not have it executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    min(Time) as Time, 
    (SELECT min(Time) FROM db_race WHERE Map='test1') as TopTime
FROM db_race
WHERE Map='test1'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Time
```

Comment: Thankyou but this doesnt work for me (Still just one row). Your first solution did except that you forgot to add the where clause. If you change that back, ill mark it as solved.

Comment: Indeed you was right with your other attemnt to help me. I cant use this query like this, since I cant use a subquery to find out the TopTime (in real its a much longer query). My goal is to have the TopTime in a second column without running 2 queries.